# How do tree automata work?

Tags: formal-languages, tree-automata

I've started with tree automata. The definition is

> (Leaf-to-root) Tree automaton $\mathcal M$ over (nonempty, finite) alphabet $\Sigma$ is quintuple $\mathcal M=(K,\Sigma,\delta,S,F)$ and bound $f$ (the fan-in bound), where $K$ is finite set of states, $S\subseteq K$ set of initial states, $F\subseteq K$set of accepting states with $\delta:A\to K$ for some (nonemty?) $A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^f\underbrace{K\times\cdots\times K}_i\times\Sigma$.

It seems ok to me, but when it comes to an example I'm lost. For example consider following tree automaton over $\{0,1\}$

[image]

I suppose $S$ is set of leaves. And now what is example of word $w$ accepted by the automaton? And how is the word read by it?

Thx a lot for help...

Comment: What you drew here is a tree, not a tree-automaton. A tree automaton is has states and transitions, and it *reads* trees, and "marks" them with its states. Then, a tree is accepted if all the leaves are marked by accepting states.

Comment: @Shaull Aaah, here it goes. :) And how is the reading done? I guess it starts with root and using $\delta$ automaton marks the root. And then what? Or am I comletely wrong?

Comment: Exactly right. The root is marked by the initial state. Then, successors of the root are marked by the state prescribed by the transition function, and so on.

Comment: Tree automata are already described in many resources. I'm not sure it's a good use of anybody's time to write yet another description, in the hope that you'll understand it. Can you be more specific about what it is that you need?